# Calculating difference on datetime row betwen rows on the same table

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, datediff, timestampdiff

I have table that holds records with tasks, status and time when triggered:

**Table tblwork:**

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+-----+
| task        | status     | stime               | id  |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+-----+
| A           | 1          | 2018-03-07 20:00:00 | 1   |
| A           | 2          | 2018-03-07 20:30:00 | 2   |
| A           | 1          | 2018-03-07 21:00:00 | 3   |
| A           | 3          | 2018-03-07 21:30:00 | 4   |
| B           | 1          | 2018-03-07 22:30:00 | 5   |
| B           | 3          | 2018-03-07 23:30:00 | 6   |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+-----+
```

Status 1 means start, 2 - pause, 3 - end

Then I need to calculate how much time is spent for each task excluding pause (status = 2). This is how I do it:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.task,
SUM(timestampdiff(second,IFNULL( 
(SELECT MAX(t2.stime) FROM tblwork t2  WHERE t2.task='B' AND t2.stime< t1.stime) ,t1.stime),t1.stime)) myTimeDiffSeconds
FROM tblwork t1 
WHERE t1.task='B' and (t1.status = 1 or t1.status = 3);
```

Now I want to get table for all tasks

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.task,
SUM(timestampdiff(second,IFNULL( 
(SELECT MAX(t2.stime) FROM tblwork t2  WHERE t2.stime< t1.stime) ,t1.stime),t1.stime)) myTimeDiffSeconds
FROM tblwork t1 
WHERE (t1.status = 1 or t1.status = 3) GROUP BY t1.taks
```

I get this result:

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| task        | id         | mytimedifference    |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| A           | 1          | 3600                |   
| B           | 3          | 2421217             |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
```

Calculation for A is correct B is wrong, it should be 3600 second but i don't understand why.

Comment: "Calculation for A is correct B is wrong" Shouldn't the mytimedifference for task `A` be 3600 seconds (1 hour) instead off 7200 seconds (2 hours)? ... start `2018-03-07 20:00:00` end `2018-03-07 21:30:00` minus 30 minutes break.

Comment: Not quite sure what the relevance of id is supposed to be; B is never associated with id = 3 in the source data.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm sorry, it way a typo.

Comment: i assume column id is a primary key with auto_increment option? And could there be more then one break before the end?

Comment: There can be more breaks before and. See this example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/050a41/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is always a start for each pause and end, wouldn't something like this be more direct?

```
SELECT t.task
   , SUM(TO_SECONDS(t.stime) 
         * CASE WHEN t.status IN (1) THEN -1
                WHEN t.status IN (2, 3) THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END
     ) AS totalTimeSecs
FROM tblwork AS task
GROUP BY t.task
```

I'm not quite sure offhand how big the values that come out of TO_SECONDS() are for current timestamps; but if they are an issue when being summed, if could be changed to

```
   , SUM((TO_SECONDS(t.stime) - some_constant_just_before_or_at_your_earliest_seconds)
         * CASE WHEN t.status IN (1) THEN -1
                WHEN t.status IN (2, 3) THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END
     ) AS totalTimeSecs
```

---

You can detect "abnormal" data by adding the following to the select expression list

```
, CASE WHEN SUM(CASE 
                WHEN t.status IN (1) THEN -1 
                WHEN t.status IN (2, 3) THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 END
              ) = 0 
       THEN 'OK' 
       ELSE 'ABNORMAL' 
   END AS integrityCheck
```

Note: any "unclosed" intervals will be marked as abnormal; without much more complicated and expensive start and end checking for intervals to differentiate "open" from "invalid", it's probably the best that can be done. *The sum used for additonal "integrityCheck" equaling -1 might hint at an open ended interval, but could also indicate an erroneous double-start.*

Comment: hm... doesn't run correctly if taks contains all of three statuses. See calculcation for D http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/050a41/1

Comment: D looks like invalid data to me; it has a "start", "pause", "stop" but is missing a resuming "start" after the "pause".

Comment: You are right. There was anomaly in data because each task must end with status 3. Thank you very much, it works perfect.