# How would I update this MySQL query to get total elapsed time from start, stop, pause and resume events

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query that I was able to create from searching through SOF.

```
SELECT
    start_log.reportID,
    start_log.userID,
    start_log.testID,
    MAX(start_log.eventDateTime) AS start_time,
    end_log.eventDateTime AS end_time,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MAX(start_log.eventDateTime), end_log.eventDateTime) AS diff
FROM
    testtracker_event AS start_log
INNER JOIN
    testtracker_event AS end_log ON (
            start_log.userID = end_log.userID
                AND
            start_log.reportID = end_log.reportID
                AND
            start_log.testID = end_log.testID
        AND
            end_log.eventDateTime > start_log.eventDateTime)
WHERE start_log.eventType = 'start'
AND end_log.eventType = 'finish'
AND start_log.testID = 2
AND start_log.userID = '$user'
GROUP BY
    start_log.userID,
    start_log.testID,
    start_log.eventDateTime,
    start_log.reportID
ORDER BY
--  userID DESC,
    start_time DESC
```

Works as expected, the query returns the difference in time from the `start_time` and `end_time` as the `diff` column. I now would like to expand this query to take into account pause and resume events I'm just having trouble understanding how I would take those into account with the current query. I could see expanding the select to account for pause and resume with columns like `pause_time` and `resume_time` except how would I account for a case that might have multiple pause and resume events? I would also venture to guess I might have to do some additional calculations to get the actual elapsed time, not sure how I would reference those either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

### Sample Data

```
reportID|testID|eventDateTime      |eventType  
--------|------|-------------------|----------  
11881   |  2   |2013-08-16 14:19:09|start  
11910   |  2   |2013-08-16 14:48:04|start  
11910   |  2   |2013-08-16 14:55:08|finish  
11891   |  2   |2013-08-16 15:01:01|start  
11891   |  2   |2013-08-16 15:25:42|finish  
11888   |  2   |2013-08-16 16:20:27|start  
11888   |  2   |2013-08-16 16:51:16|finish  
11889   |  2   |2013-08-19 09:00:13|start  
11889   |  2   |2013-08-19 10:31:17|finish  
11905   |  2   |2013-08-19 12:10:00|start  
11898   |  2   |2013-08-19 12:12:02|start  
11898   |  2   |2013-08-19 12:19:28|finish  
11905   |  2   |2013-08-19 12:27:21|finish  
11880   |  2   |2013-08-19 16:40:26|start  
11880   |  2   |2013-08-19 16:40:27|finish  
11895   |  2   |2013-08-19 16:42:58|start  
11895   |  2   |2013-08-19 16:55:14|finish  
11908   |  2   |2013-08-20 09:46:11|start  
11908   |  2   |2013-08-20 09:56:20|finish  
11862   |  2   |2013-08-20 10:20:11|start  
11862   |  2   |2013-08-20 10:29:44|finish  
11911   |  2   |2013-08-20 11:31:33|start  
11911   |  2   |2013-08-20 11:59:15|finish  
11913   |  2   |2013-08-20 12:44:07|start  
11913   |  2   |2013-08-20 13:32:52|finish  
11928   |  2   |2013-08-20 14:28:38|start  
11928   |  2   |2013-08-20 14:40:00|finish  
11836   |  2   |2013-08-20 16:26:03|start  
11887   |  2   |2013-08-20 16:30:36|start  
11836   |  2   |2013-08-20 16:43:53|finish  
11887   |  2   |2013-08-20 16:58:44|pause  
11902   |  2   |2013-08-22 14:51:53|start  
11902   |  2   |2013-08-22 15:01:05|finish  
11912   |  2   |2013-08-22 15:01:43|start  
11912   |  2   |2013-08-22 15:12:21|finish  
11930   |  2   |2013-08-22 16:09:22|start  
11814   |  2   |2013-08-14 10:39:07|finish  
11930   |  2   |2013-08-23 09:55:14|finish  
11914   |  2   |2013-08-26 14:55:04|start  
11914   |  2   |2013-08-26 15:19:48|pause  
11940   |  2   |2013-08-27 07:44:12|start  
11940   |  2   |2013-08-27 07:55:52|finish  
11914   |  2   |2013-08-27 09:13:28|resume  
11914   |  2   |2013-08-27 09:13:44|pause  
11914   |  2   |2013-08-27 09:15:56|resume  
11914   |  2   |2013-08-27 09:30:12|finish
```

Dropped userId column form the sample to protect identities.

**Not the expected result for `reportID - 11914`**

```
reportID|testID|start|end|diff  
--------|------|-----|---|-----  
11914 | 2 |2013-08-26 14:55:04|2013-08-27 09:30:12|1115
```

**Expected result for `reportID - 11902`**

```
reportID|testID|start|end|diff  
--------|------|-----|---|-----  
11902 | 2 | 2013-09-10 14:26:53 | 2013-09-10 14:45:36 | 18
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results.

Comment: Is that good? && is there like a SQLbin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating difference on datetime row betwen rows on the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661342/calculating-difference-on-datetime-row-betwen-rows-on-the-same-table)

Comment: The specifics is a bit of a pain to work out, but basically you'll need to to use a select .... , diff - sum(eventDateTimeDiffs_Pause_Resume)